# iPadOS からのアクセスをモバイルと認識させたい

Tags: javascript, php

htmlとCSSしかまともにやってこなかったWEBデザイナーだったのですが、Laravelで開発してあるWEBアプリの改修をしています。

iPad13以降の端末からのアクセス時にモバイル版サイトを表示したいとの案件が来ました。
別アプリではcookieを書き出し、cookieの中にmobileとの文字列があればmobile判定しているやり方をしています。
Laravelのアプリではmobile判定された場合にmobile.phpを呼び出すような指定がされているので、iPad13以降の端末でアクセスした際にmobileだと判定させたいのですが、やり方が分かりません。
ご教授頂けましたら幸いです。

追記
jsファイルで実装しているのではないかと・・・

```
heckDeviceType({ dispatch, commit, state }){
        let ua = navigator.userAgent,
            isWindowsPhone = /(?:Windows Phone)/.test(ua),
            isSymbian = /(?:SymbianOS)/.test(ua) || isWindowsPhone,
            isAndroid = /(?:Android)/.test(ua),
            isFireFox = /(?:Firefox)/.test(ua),
            isChrome = /(?:Chrome|CriOS)/.test(ua),
            isTablet = /(?:iPad|PlayBook)/.test(ua) || (isAndroid && !/(?:Mobile)/.test(ua)) || (isFireFox && /(?:Tablet)/.test(ua),
            isPhone = /(?:iPhone)/.test(ua) && !isTablet,
            isPc = !isPhone && !isAndroid && !isSymbian;
        let os = {
            isTablet: isTablet,
            isPhone: isPhone,
            isAndroid: isAndroid,
            isPc: isPc
        }

        commit("getDeviceType",os);
    },
```

追記：
ありがとうございます。isTabletならツールバーをfalse、それ以外のDeviceTypeならtrue と下記のソースにしか見当たりませんでした。 async created() { this.checkDeviceType(); this.$store.commit('home/setUsingPublicHash', false); this.$store.state.home.title = ''; this.startVisibilityWatch(); もう少しソースコード解析してみます。

追記：
isphoneに追加してみましたがダメでした。 書き方が違うのでしょうか？そもそもこういう事ではないのでしょうか？ isPhone = /(?:iPhone)/.test(ua) && !isTablet|| (/android|ipod|ipad|iphone|macintosh/.test(ua) && 'ontouchend' in document) ,

追記：
ismobileで分岐している箇所もありました。
Mobile-Detectも仕様しているようでした。PHP自体は元々のGitHubのURLにリンクしているようです。

Comment: Laravel標準にはモバイル判定する機能はついていないのでおそらく何らかの方法で実装しているのかと推察します。その実装部分をどのように判定しているのか質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: なるほど、判定処理は共通関数で提供しているのですね。iPad13以降を判定して、isPhoneをtrueにすることはできると思いますが、それ以外でheckDeviceTypeの呼び出し先でどのように利用しているのか調査しないとiPad13以降をisPhoneをtrueにすることの不都合がありそうです。さすがに頑張ってソースコードを読み込んでもらわないといけなさそうです

Comment: 残念ながら一問一答で行うレベルの質問ではなく範囲が広そうです。もはやアプリの改修依頼のレベルになっています。それだけでお金が取れるレベルです。ここで言えるのは判定している部分とその判定結果を利用している箇所を修正をするしかないと思います。

Comment: 難しい質問に丁寧にお答えいただきありがとうございました。